# String match with field in logs

Tags: splunk

This is for splunk.

We have event start and completion log with IDs. So initially we will have log say "Event started for id:[aaa]" and then we will have "Event completed for id:[aaa]"

How do I make a table which goes like this or something similar?

```
Eventid                   Completed   
aaa                       Yes   
bbb                       No
```

I tried extracting a field from "aaa" managed to write a search which returns me a list of IDs. Question is how do I do a search for each ID returned and then match and put them into a table?

Comment: Do you want to write it to csv or something?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot of information in your post but here is some horrible code I've written to do this in python. This will get the data you want so you'll just need to add a line to write it to a new line of a table of whatever format you wish (csv etc).

```
with open('yourdata.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        substring = line[:7]
        if substring == "Event s":
            firstSplit = line.split("]")
            secondSplit = firstSplit[0] .split('[') 
            // if something write data: secondSplit[1]
        elif substring == "Event c":
            firstSplit = line.split("]")
            secondSplit = firstSplit[0] .split('[') 
            // if something else write data: secondSplit[1]
```